# getting pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims with airflow helm2 chart

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I have a k8s cluster on 3 nodes running with vagrants in my laptop

I'm following this tutorial : 
https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/deploy-apache-airflow-kubernetes-helm/

And at the 2nd command :

```
helm install myrelease bitnami/airflow 
--set airflow.cloneDagFilesFromGit.enabled=true 
--set airflow.cloneDagFilesFromGit.repository=REPOSITORY_URL  
--set airflow.cloneDagFilesFromGit.branch=master 
--set airflow.baseUrl=http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

I'm getting a "pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims" on the myrelease-postgresql-0 pod.

I can see that postgresql is a dependency : 
https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-chart/blob/master/requirements.yaml

but i don't know how to fix it as i don't have the possibility to change a dependency conf ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you run kubectl get events -n namespace_name

Answer (score 2):

I ran the helm install without any issues:

```
> helm list
NAME        NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART           APP VERSION
myrelease   kafka       1           2020-05-18 12:34:17.448554945 +0530 IST deployed    airflow-6.2.2   1.10.10

> kubectl get pv,pvc -n kafka
NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                       STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pvc-dedbb5f6-844d-4e34-8eae-21e8187afd24   8Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    kafka/data-myrelease-postgresql-0           local-path              2m12s
persistentvolume/pvc-22222462-1a42-476a-a5dc-5fd0dc6a6e6b   8Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    kafka/redis-data-myrelease-redis-slave-0    local-path              2m10s
persistentvolume/pvc-c1c216a3-92e6-4c88-bd1c-670fe25c3c12   8Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    kafka/redis-data-myrelease-redis-master-0   local-path              2m10s
persistentvolume/pvc-535672be-64c0-4551-99b0-9cc0ca8fbbd1   8Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    kafka/redis-data-myrelease-redis-slave-1    local-path              83s

NAME                                                        STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/data-myrelease-postgresql-0           Bound    pvc-dedbb5f6-844d-4e34-8eae-21e8187afd24   8Gi        RWO            local-path     2m19s
persistentvolumeclaim/redis-data-myrelease-redis-slave-0    Bound    pvc-22222462-1a42-476a-a5dc-5fd0dc6a6e6b   8Gi        RWO            local-path     2m19s
persistentvolumeclaim/redis-data-myrelease-redis-master-0   Bound    pvc-c1c216a3-92e6-4c88-bd1c-670fe25c3c12   8Gi        RWO            local-path     2m19s
persistentvolumeclaim/redis-data-myrelease-redis-slave-1    Bound    pvc-535672be-64c0-4551-99b0-9cc0ca8fbbd1   8Gi        RWO            local-path     92s
```

I believe you might not have a `storageClass` to provision a PVC for the PV requested by your PostgreSQL pod.

Refer: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/airflow/values.yaml#L9